Use of the verb 'to introduce'
Can I use the verb 'to introduce' if I describe my farm,being somewhere else?
For example: 'let me introduce my farm' or 'let me introduce you to my farm.
Thx!

It's fine. Let me introduce you to Gravetye Manor gardens - the grounds include a wild garden, a flower garden, a kitchen garden, an orchard, a wild meadow by a lake and more

Standard etiquette is you introduce the lower-status person to the one with higher status, but using this form with inanimate objects is usually facetious, mock-ceremonial, or outright sarcastic/rude.

You would need an extraordinary context to justify "let me introduce" something, if you don't want it to sound unduly dramatic.  For example, you're meeting with some tour guides and you are meeting in a hotel somewhere, to talk about your farm as a possible tour destination.  But if you're sitting on an airplane, say, it might be better to say to the person next to you, "Would you like to see some pictures of my farm?" rather than "Let me introduce my farm".

If the object of the introduction isn't present, then that sense of "introduce" would have to be followed by a description, or a showing of photographs or something else that represents the object of the introduction.
But yes, you can use it that way.

A verbal description would do, I think.

No, you can't; in this context it refers specifically to people.  The Cambridge dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/introduce defines this use of introduce as "to tell someone another person's name the first time that they meet"
You could use something like "Let me tell you about my farm"

But... Introduce 2. verb If you introduce someone to something, you cause them to learn about it or experience it for the first time. He introduced us to the delights of natural food. Collins Dictionary
